# Equivalent of open(O_WRONLY | O_CREAT) in GLib?

Tags: c, glib, vala, gio

I need to open a file for writing. If the file already exists, I don't want to truncate it.

In other words, in plain C I'd do:

```
int fd = open("output.bin", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
// I don't mind using O_RDWR, btw.
```

I'm trying to do something similar with GLib's GFile (part of GIO). I first tried:

```
g_file_create(gfile, G_FILE_CREATE_NONE, NULL, NULL);
```

But this fails if the file already exists.

I see that there are [about 5 other functions](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html) that return `GFileOutputStream` or `GFileIOStream`, but I don't quite see one that does what I want.

**Am I missing something?**

Do I need to split this simple task into several small ones? (checking for file existence; if exists, create, otherwise open; all wrapped somehow in a lock.)

(BTW, if it matters: my file will reside on the local filesystem, not a networked one. Also, I'm working in Vala, which is why I don't simply use `open()` (maybe I could find bindings for it, but I prefer to learn the GIO way of doing things).)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any such function. Perhaps you can check if the return code from `g_file_create` is [`G_IO_ERROR_EXISTS`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GIOError.html#G-IO-ERROR-EXISTS:CAPS) and not treat it as failure?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing this in two steps. I used @usr's suggestion of checking for `G_IO_ERROR_EXISTS`. My code:

```
public class Downloader {

  public FileIOStream iostream;

  public OutputStream output { get { return iostream.output_stream; } }

  public void create_output_file() throws Error
  {
    File file = File.new_for_path("output.bin");
    try {
      // If file doesn't exist.
      iostream = file.create_readwrite(NONE);
    } catch (Error e) {
      if (e is IOError.EXISTS)
        // It exists.
        iostream = file.open_readwrite();
      else
        throw e;
    }
  }

}
```

(There could be a race condition here, but it's irrelevant in my case.)

Answer (score 2):

The Valadoc.org documentation has good examples so I won't code up a working example here. I think you need [`GLib.File.new_for_path ()`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.new_for_path.html) and [`GLib.File.append_to ()`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.append_to.html). The C documentation for [`g_file_append_to ()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-append-to) advises 'Gets an output stream for appending data to the file. If the file doesn't already exist it is created.' Note that `append_to ()` takes a [`FileCreateFlags`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.FileCreateFlags.html) argument. There is also an asynchronous version of `append_to ()` for Vala, [`append_to_async ()`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.File.append_to_async.html).

By the way the Vala binding for `open ()` is in the Posix VAPI. See [`open ()`](https://valadoc.org/posix/Posix.open.html), [`O_WRONLY`](https://valadoc.org/posix/Posix.O_WRONLY.html) and [`O_CREAT`](https://valadoc.org/posix/Posix.O_CREAT.html) at Valadoc.org.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use `append_to()` because I won't be writing at the end of the file but at some random position within. (And thanks for the Posix pointers: it's nice to see that this binding is effectively built-in.)

Comment: `append_to ()` returns a `FileOutputStream` that has a `seek` method. The `append_to ()` sets the current position to the end of the file that's all, but you can change the position if needs be.

Comment: Not so. `append_to()` has the semantic of O_APPEND, whom the man page of `open(2)` describes as: "Before **each** write(2), the file offset is positioned at the end of the file [...] performed as a single atomic step". I've [just verified](https://pastebin.com/yNgWY3tF) that this holds true for Vala's GIO as well.

Answer (score 1):

The official upstream answer is that GIO, as a high-level abstraction layer, was not originally designed to give guarantees about atomic create-or-open operations (as with `O_CREAT`), so you have two options:

- Try creating the file and, if that fails with `G_IO_ERROR_EXISTS`, try opening it instead; as in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50455733/2931197).
- Create/Open the file using `open()` with `O_CREAT` (as in the question), and pass the FD to [`g_unix_output_stream_new()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GUnixOutputStream.html#g-unix-output-stream-new) to create a new `GOutputStream` which wraps the FD and you can write to as if it were returned by [`g_file_create()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-create).

Note that `g_unix_output_stream_new()` isn’t portable to non-Unix platforms, but that doesn’t appear to be relevant in your case. This second option is the recommended one if you do care about eliminating race conditions.

Note that there are other reasons to avoid the race condition: less code, fewer syscalls (which means better performance), and more readable code (if you ignore the abrupt naming of the `open()` APIs).

Doing this directly with a method on `GFile` may be supported in future: there’s an [open issue about supporting it](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/issues/1411) in GLib.